# Appium/Selenium Slider value

Tags: c#, selenium, uwp, slider, appium

I am writing a Appium UI tests for my UWP application.

With next code I am getting the control:

```
var slider = session.FindElementByClassName("Slider");
```

For taking it's value I have tried:

```
slider.Text;
slider.TagName;
slider.GetAttribute("Value");
```

But none of them returns value of slider.

Any way of getting it?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to inspect the html of this slider. There will be some attribute which store the value of the slider. [For more details about the slider-html you can refer to this link.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp)

If you paste your html for the slider, I can help you.

Comment: It's a UWP application, so there is no HTML of slider.